# What to do when there's is no ground wire available in old box?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I recently decided to change my hallway light. My house was built in 71 so the wiring is obviously not that new. I used a voltage meter to determine my hot and neutral wire but I have no idea how to ground it. I see two ground wires attached to a ground screw (I believe).

The old fixture was not grounded at all.

Anybody have any idea how to ground it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Pictures, please. [Edit] to add them. The old fixture may have been grounded via attachment to a metal box. If you have two ground wires, there's clearly ground wire available...

Comment: so what is your problem ?? yu have ground wires, just use them

Answer (score 3):

If new fixture has a ground wire, then just connect grounds together with wire nuts/wagos, plus to the screw in the box.

Quite a few light fixtures are not grounded, but the boxes are. Plastic fixture plus glass bulb means no electric path(usually).

Answer (score 3):

The photo shows 2 ground wires under the screw so the box is grounded, many light fixtures have a metal strap that when connected to the metal box is the ground path.

The green screw on the strap is used to ground the fixture.

To make a proper ground the ground in the cable with the hot should go under the screw if long enough.  In my jurisdiction I have to run that ground directly to the screw so I use special green wirenuts that allow 1 wire to pass through and then the others to be twisted at the nut.

if the wires are two short for a direct bond to the box as this may be then pigtailing is allowed used to require crimp connectors but had been relaxed to listed wire connectors

So you can use a metal strap if your fixture came with one if not the 2 grounds need to be tied with the fixture ground and a box ground jumper.

Comment: Alright so if I keep the hot wires ground connected to the screw and wire nut the neutrals ground with the fixture ground I should be good?

Comment: The neutrals are not connected to ground at anyplace other than the main panel. I can not quite see the connections but it is possible this is a switch leg, with a switch leg the incoming hot from the panel goes to the switch since you have black, red,white,ground  the power may go down on the black and the switched come back on the red, or  the hot may go down on the white and have the possibility of a black and red switched for ceiling fan / light combos this was the popular way to wire them in the 70’s. Basically you need to wire it the same and either use a strap or pigtail the grounds.

Comment: @TomG no, this isn't cars or DC electronics. **Neutral Is Not Ground**.  In AC power we wire both sides of the circuit - supply and return - as if they are hot wires (because, sometimes neutral is hot! Not supposed to happen but it does, so we build for it). Everything is isolated from safety ground except at one specific bonding point.  Ed, since the box is grounded, couldn't the lamp just pick up ground via its mounting screws?  Or yeah, a ground clip would do.

Comment: @harper read any op the answer or comments they all say that light fixtures usually have a strap or screws either is ok I provided this information with the proper way to bond or ground everything including stating that the only place ground and neutral are connected is in the main panel.